# shr: render local images

Tags: htmlize, shr

I'd like to use the internal shr "package" of emacs to display local images. The thing is that I can display online images but not local ones, that's quite strange isn't it!

Reproduce:
Put in a random buffer this file:

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Extern file:<br/>
      <img src="http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/karnataka/article19571557.ece/alternates/FREE_300/28BGMYSMONKEY" alt="Extern file"/>
    </p>
    <p>Intern file:<br/>
      <img src="/tmp/monk/Trois-singes-644x427.jpg" alt="No local"/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And call `M-x shr-render-buffer`. The online image is displayed, not the local one...
[image]

-- EDIT --
After the proposition of the comment, I upload the full html I'm using, as well as a screenshot. I'm also using GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30).

[image]

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Extern file:<br/>
      <img src="http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/karnataka/article19571557.ece/alternates/FREE_300/28BGMYSMONKEY" alt="Extern file"/>
    </p>
    <p>Intern file:<br/>
      <img src="file:///tmp/monk/Trois-singes-644x427.jpg" alt="No local"/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

-- EDIT 2 --
I have no idea why, but I tried to restart emacs and try again (same code with `file:///tmp/...` for sure because it was saved in a file), and now it works perfectly... I've no idea what happened, I need to investigate. Thank you!

Comment: Try prepending `file://` to the local file name,

Comment: @Basil It's not working either

Comment: Works for me on Emacs versions 24-27.  Are you sure you are writing `file:///tmp/...` and not `file://tmp/...`? Can you please update your question with the precise new HTML you are trying to render? What is your `emacs-version`? Does it work if you start Emacs with the `-Q` flag?

Comment: @Basil Very strange: since the beginning I was using `file:///tmp/...` and it was not working. So I tried `-Q`, it worked! Then I restarted emacs normally, and tried again... And it worked! No idea what appened, if this appends again I'll be back here. Meanwhile, thank you very much!